# How do I send a state to a conditional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem..

please help me.

i'm working react js

How do I send a state to a conditional react component?

```
this.state = {
 isTrue: false,
 name: undefined
}

handleClick(e){
 this.setState({
  isTrue: true,
  name: 'adwin'
 })
}

//////// render return ///////

{this.state.isTrue ? (
  <App2 name={this.state.name} />
 ) : ''
}



////// in App2 component //////
componentDidMount(){
 console.log(this.props.name)  //>>> it work undefined
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing prop to the child component is correct. You can try to pass `props` as an argument in the constructor of the child component like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
     isTrue: false,
     name: undefined
    }
   }
  

  handleClick = (e) => {
   this.setState({
    isTrue: true,
    name: 'adwin'
   })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isTrue ? (
          <App2 name={this.state.name} />
         ) : ''
        }
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class App2 extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   }
  componentDidMount(){
   console.log(this.props.name)  
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.name}
      </div>
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're only looking for a conditional you can do `{this.state.isTrue && <App2 name={this.state.name} />}`